# How do fabrics become stretchy?

Tags: everyday-life, matter

What makes stretchyness happen? I know it has something to do with the way the threads are sewed together, right?

Comment: Some fabrics are stretchy because they are made of stretchy fibers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_elasticity

Comment: Some fabrics are stretchy because their open weave allows [easy bending of fibers that *aren't* stretchy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359835X14003510).

Comment: The two comments above, with a bit of elaboration, are an answer.